# get time until next output

Tags: io, real-time

Some kinds of I/O operate at exact frequencies. Under extreme latency requirements, it would be useful to know how much time there is until the next piece of data is due to arrive on a certain fd.

For example, consider a stream processor which must output data to hardware at some predetermined points in time. Suppose the stream's content depends on some input. In order to reduce latency from input to output, the stream processor should wait for input for as long as possible before rendering the next piece of data. In order to do that, though, the processor needs to know how much time is left before the data is required.

Are there extensions to the standard unix I/O library (unistd.h, read(), write(), file descriptors, etc.) that allow data streams to operate in a mode where you can determine the time until the next I/O operation? Is there a word for this kind of I/O extension?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more precise about your question. Technically speaking, you need to start a timer once one output is debugged and then stop it after a second output is debugged